# Keras loss output doesn't change - activation and open topics checked

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently struggling with my CNN.
I use the categorial_crossentropy and I will add on my model.
Neither the acc increases nor decreases the loss.
The amount of labeled data is now 600, which is fairly small, but no changes at all seem pretty strange to me.

```
### Define architecture.
model.add(Conv2D(32, 4, strides=(11,11),padding="same",input_shape=(200,200,3), activation="relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(64, 4, strides=(9,9),padding="same", activation="relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(128, 4, strides=(5,5),padding="same", activation="relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())

model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))

model.add(Dense(y_test.shape[1], activation="sigmoid"))

model.summary()

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1,) #0.1
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model1 = model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1)

Epoch 1/10
420/420 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 1.4598 - acc: 0.2381

Epoch 2/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4679 - acc: 0.2333

Epoch 3/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4335 - acc: 0.2667

Epoch 4/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4198 - acc: 0.2310

Epoch 5/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4038 - acc: 0.2524

Epoch 6/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4343 - acc: 0.2643

Epoch 7/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4281 - acc: 0.2786

Epoch 8/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4097 - acc: 0.2333

Epoch 9/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4071 - acc: 0.2714

Epoch 10/10
420/420 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4135 - acc: 0.2476
```

Is there something wrong with my model? 
I tried changing the lr, the size of the pictures, tried to simplfy the model, changed the kernelsize, let it run for more epochs( up to 60) and printed the prediction for x_test.
The prediciton seemed wrong aswell:

```
error = model.predict(x_test)

print(error)

[[0.49998534 0.49998534 0.4999715  0.50000155]

 [0.49998188 0.49998283 0.49997032 0.5000029 ]

 [0.49998188 0.4999858  0.49998164 0.5000036 ]

 [0.4999795  0.49998736 0.4999841  0.5000008 ]

 [0.49998784 0.49997187 0.49996948 0.5000013 ]

 [0.49997532 0.49997967 0.49997616 0.50000024]
```

Every kind of help is very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If this is indeed a 4-class classification problem, as it seems, `sigmoid` is not an appropriate activation function for your last layer - you should change it to `softmax`.

Comment: Also a lr of 0.1 might be too big, always start using the default values of keras.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you several things based on my experiences for you to try:

- Since you are using categorical crossentropy, you can try 'softmax' as an activation function instead of 'sigmoid' at the last layer.
- You should decrease your learning rate. (With new settings suggested here)
- You may try to use different optimizer such as 'adam' instead of 'sgd'.
- You can delete dropout and batch normalization layers and add them only if they are necessary.
- Make your kernels dimension [2x2] instead of 1. Change kernel size from 4 to (3x3) maybe. Also decrease size of strides, maybe you can start with (1,1). Using kernel with size 4 on image with dimension [200x200] with strides (11,11) is almost equal to learning 'nothing'.

Please try final suggestion first as it seems like the main problem. I hope one of these may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below setting:

- Reduce the strides to 1*1 or 2*2 or at the max 3*3
- Remove the dropouts between Convolutional layers, use dropouts only before dense layers, if necessary
- Try adding pooling layers, preferably of strides 2*2 and kernel size of 2*2 after Convolutional layers.
- Change optimization to adam/nadam
- Use softmax instead of sigmoid
- Increase the number of epochs, 10 is too low.

All the above points can vary depending upon the problem, never the less, you can give a try, and modify the model accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you lose almost all the spatial information in the image in the first two layer because of the strides you used.

your `model.summary()` shows the problem:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 19, 19, 32)        1568      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 19, 19, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 19, 19, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 3, 3, 64)          32832     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 3, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 3, 3, 64)          256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 1, 128)         131200    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 1, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 1, 1, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_1 (Glob (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 516       
=================================================================
Total params: 183,524
Trainable params: 183,076
Non-trainable params: 448
```

what you see is an immediate drop in tensor size from 200 in the original image to 19 after the first convolution, and to 3 after the second. we would expect a much more gradual decrease in size in order to really use the advantage of the convolutional layers.

if you keep your code as is and change all the strides to`(2, 2)` you will get a much more reasonable structure:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 100, 100, 32)      1568      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 100, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 100, 100, 32)      128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 50, 50, 64)        32832     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 50, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 50, 50, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 25, 25, 128)       131200    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 25, 25, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 25, 25, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_1 (Glob (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 516       
=================================================================
Total params: 183,524
Trainable params: 183,076
Non-trainable params: 448
_________________________________________________________________
```